# Piezoelectric driver circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, piezo

This circuit is used to drive the piezo actuator used in external cavity diode lasers to tune the frequency of the laser. I don't understand the purpose of Op-amp U9 and the other transistors used. Specifically the Q3 transistor attached to the Darlington pair. I also find it hard to understand the feedback mechanism of the Op-amp U9. I am a physics student having very little background in electronics, so:

1. What use have Op-amp U9, and Q3?
2. How does the feedback from U9 work?

[image]

Comment: Hi there! If you could be so kind and add the source for that picture as well, so copyright etc is satisfied. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Q3 is acting as an emitter-follower.  This provides non-inverting current gain but not voltage gain.  Its function is to create a low output impedance to drive the output, and to provide more output current than U9 can source on its own.

The Darlington pair is, from a circuit gain point of view, an inverter with gain.  Because this inverter is in the circuit and feedback loop between the output of U6 and R16, it *effectively* swaps the polarities of the two U9 inputs.  Thus, pin 3 is the inverting input, driven by the output through R4 and R3.  Then set the gain for this part of the circuit to 15.

Locally, U9 is an opamp independent of the extra-large loop around it.  As far as its pin 6 output is concerned, pin 6 is its inverting input.  If I understand things correctly, R1 makes the opamp perform as a unity-gain voltage follower.  Thus, all of the voltage gain in the circuit comes from the darlington pair, and U9 is a differential input voltage buffer.  No idea why the original designer did this; one possibility has to do with loop stability.

The Darlington pair and the output emitter follower are referenced to GND, so the output signal, whatever it is, cannot swing below GND.

Without more information about the driving signal's frequency, waveshape, voltage, and offset, some things cannot be determined.